# Global name is not defined when using global variable

Tags: python

I am learning Python as I go and I am not getting what I am doing wrong with my variables and being to access them in functions.

I have recreated the general layout of my script in PythonFiddle and I got the same error

```
global trigger

class test(object):
    def init(self):
        trigger = 'hi'
        self.step2()

    def step2(self):
        print '%s' % trigger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tester = test()
    tester.init()`
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please learn not to use `global`. That's what parameters and return values are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the variable as global in every function where you assign to it.  Put `global trigger` inside your `init` method.

Note that doing things this way is probably not a great idea.  There's not much point to defining a class if it's just going to store its data in a global variable.  One alternative would be:

```
class test(object):
    def init(self):
        self.trigger = 'hi'
        self.step2()

    def step2(self):
        print '%s' % self.trigger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tester = test()
    tester.init()
```

Comment: I should probably pass it as an argument into the functions eh? What would be the tweaks to the example above to have it proper?

Comment: @DeucePie: I edited my answer to add an example.  One way is to store the value as an attribute of the object.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped but I have run into another error down the line with the variable in another function but being used to form some JSON. If I make it {'filename': trigger} I get global name is not defined or if i make it {'filename': self.trigger} it says TypeError: <type 'type'> is not JSON serializable

Comment: @DeucePie: You should probably ask a separate question about that, as it sounds like an unrelated issue and that's not part of the code that you posted.

Comment: I will in 60 minutes... ;-)